# Herkunft des Wortes "eventuell"

Tags: etymology, english

Sind das Wort "eventuell" und das englische Wort "eventually" verwandt? Falls sie doch eine gemeinsame Abstammung haben, warum sind ihre Bedeutungen ganz anders?

Wenn nicht, was ist die Herkunft dieses Wortes?

Comment: Ein paar hilfreiche Infos kann man hier finden https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/419390/how-did-the-meaning-of-eventually-diverge-from-the-french-german-meanings

Comment: Möchte lieber auf Deutsch lesen

Comment: Na gut ich kann das selbst machen, aber ich bin hergekommen teilweise auch um mein Deutsch zu üben, nicht mein Englisch...

Comment: https://www.dwds.de/wb/eventuell
https://www.etymonline.com/word/eventual

Comment: @CarstenS Das antwortet meine Frage nicht, ob sie verwandt sind.

Comment: @sermonionx Welche Recherchen hast du selbst unternommen, um deine Frage zu beantworten?

Comment: @sermonionx, deshalb ist es ja auch ein Kommentar und keine Antwort ;) Ich denke aber, dass das ausreichende Ressourcen sind, um die Frage zu beantworten.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Die Bedeutungen von deutsch *eventuell* und Englisch *eventual* sind nicht grundsätzlich unterschiedlich. Das Wort geht in beiden Sprache zurück auf "*sich auf ein Ereignis beziehend*". Die beiden Bedeutungsvarianten haben sich daraus entwickelt. - Wie man im letzten Absatz unten sieht, soll die heutige Bedeutung im Englischen allerdings recht modern sein, nämlich von 1823.

**Deutsch**

Das Adjektiv *eventuell* (mit der Bedeutung "möglicherweise, vielleicht"<sup>1</sup>) wurde im 18. Jahrhundert aus dem gleichbedeutenden französischen *éventuel* entlehnt, das wiederum auf mittellateinisch *eventualis* zurückgeht. Zugrunde liegt das lateinische *evenire* (herauskommen, eintreffen, sich ereignen), eine Bildung zu *venire* (kommen). - Diese Erklärung findet man im Duden Herkunftswörterbuch unter *eventuell*.

**Englisch**

Für das Englische *eventual*, das natürlich auf die gleichen Wurzeln zurückgeht, erfährt man bei Etymonline.com, dass es seit 1610 in geschriebener Verwendung bekannt ist und zwar im Sinne von "sich auf Ereignisse beziehend". Auch fürs Englische wird davon ausgegangen, dass es von französisch *éventuel* und darum letztlich von lateinisch *evenire* kommt. Die heutige Bedeutung ("schließlich", "letztendlich", "im Resultat") habe *eventual* (bzw. das Adverb *eventually*) allerdings erst 1823 angenommen. - Leider wird in Etymonline.com diese erste Fundstelle für die abweichende Bedeutung nicht genauer bezeichnet.<sup>2</sup>

---

Anmerkungen

<sup>1</sup> Ich finde es persönlich unglücklich, die Bedeutung eines Adjektives mit quasi-synonymen *Adverbien* zu beschreiben. Da das aber - wohl der Kürze wegen - im zitierten Duden Herkunftswörterbuch genau so gehandhabt wird und jede andere Lösung umständlich wäre, habe ich es jetzt mal so übernommen.
<sup>2</sup> Wer **zum Bedeutungswandel des Wortes im Englischen** mehr wissen möchte, kann im Schwesterforum nachschauen: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/419390/how-did-the-meaning-of-eventually-diverge-from-the-french-german-meanings (wie Kommentator Nico ja oben schon angemerkt hatte). Dort wird der Bedeutungswandel ausführlicher diskutiert. Im Kern wird dort die These vertreten, dass bereits im lateinischen Wort *ēventus* zwei Bedeutungen angelegt seien, nämlich *possibility* (Möglichkeit) und *finality* (Ende, Ausgang). Moderne Lexika des Englischen tendierten aber dazu, die *possibility*-Bedeutung als veraltet zu bezeichnen.